# Java Swing - Refresh jTable using Timer

Tags: java, swing, swingbuilder

I have 2 simple database query `JTable` (Client and Server).

Client has all functions like view records, print, save PDF etc.
Server auto refresh database records to table with a timer of 30secs. (Not yet implemented.)

My problem is I can display the database records to table with no issue with the following code.

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SQL");
ResultSet rs = pst.ExecuteQuery();
jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

But I wish to implement the auto refreshing of table with the above code with a timer.

Example, I inserted the codes into a methods called public void `Update_Records()`. How am I supposed to use the timer to call the method to display the records into the table every 30 secs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      updateRecords();
   }
});

timer.setDelay(30000); // delay for 30 seconds
timer.start();
```

*Aside:* Java naming conventions have methods starting with lowercase and underscores are generally not used so `Update_Records` becomes `updateRecords`.

Comment: make sure it's `javax.swing.Timer`, not `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried the codes but somehow it kept adding full data into my jTable. Is there any way it will refresh new data instead of adding whole data into the jTable?